# Compressed audio encoding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encoding, mp3, windows-phone-7.1

In my Windows Phone 7 (Mango) project, I'm capturing microphone output and streaming it to a service using sockets.  The mic output format is PCM - which is of course quite huge.  I'd like to encode/compress it before streaming it out.  I've not been successful finding an audio (e.g. mp3) encoding library written in C# that will compile/run on WP7.  Are there any out there?

The other off-the-shelf option I've investigated, using an LZ-based library like SharpCompress, only gives me about 15% savings so that isn't really much help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I have found [NSpeex](http://nspeex.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.  The silverlight version seems to work in a WP7 project so far (even though the project system warned it may not).  I haven't fully tested yet, but so far this looks promising...

Comment: After spending some time with NSpeex, I can report that it achieves excellent compression ratios for speech - e.g. I've been able to compress about 50K into 1K for a 98% deflate ratio - far better than LZ.  Unfortunately it is also very CPU-intensive, but setting the Quality at the low end (e.g. 1 out of 10) still produces a reasonable quality encoding and takes less than half of the CPU.

Comment: Omri, please post the code you use to encode and decode your raw mic data on Windows Phone. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here's a gist with the code I used to encode the stream.  https://gist.github.com/3366917